# Automated packaging and deployment of web services to Oracle Application Server 10g

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, ant, oracle10g

Good day!

Currently I have an annotated class files (inteface and implementation) of web services. The logic of these web services are on a jar file (Enterprise Java Beans). The web services are being compiled, packaged and deployed to **Oracle Application Server 10g**  using **JDeveloper 10.1.3.3**.

Our organization is adapting **Continuous Integration** in our software development. Hence, one of the task is to automate the build of applications using ant.

Is there a **tool** (i.e. ant, jar, cmd) that will automate:

- packaging and
- deployment

of **stateless web services** from **annotated java class** files?

I found the following from [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13982/wsdeployment.htm) that I can use WebServiceAssembler. I tried the following ant task:

```
<oracle:assemble appName="myService" 
          output="build"
          input="myservice.jar 
          >
          <oracle:porttype
            interfaceName="com.myCompany.myService.Hello"
            className="com.mycompany.HelloImpl"/> 
</oracle:assemble>
```

However, this ant task will only package and deploy a single web service (i.e. only the Hello). Is there a way to package all web services from myservices.jar?

Another question, how can I include in package libraries in which web services are dependent?